# Trying to initate guided access from within an iOS6 app?

Tags: iphone, ios, guided-access

We have an iOS6 (iPhone) app we are building in XCode that lists installed apps on the user's device (who have registered URLs) in a list View. Is it possible to make one of the apps in the list open in Guided Access mode (if Guided Access is turned on beforehand)? Basically, we want to bypass the triple click on the home button and make any app in the list open directly to the Guided Access Start Screen.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Apple](http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/),

> Guided Access helps students with disabilities such as autism remain
>   on task and focused on content. It allows a parent, teacher, or
>   administrator to limit an iOS device to one app by disabling the Home
>   button, as well as restrict touch input on certain areas of the
>   screen.

It's pretty clear that Apple will forbid launch of other applications.

Answer (score 1):

There is no current way to initiate guided access mode via API; the ONLY method is for the user to do it (settings, tripple click home, etc.).  Some testing apps say they test (via API call) to insure the app is in guided access mode or they won't run their test.  Looking for that API call now.

Comment: found it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled